# Concatenate network path + variable

Tags: powershell

How can I concatenate this path with this variable?

```
$file = "My file 01.txt" #The file name contains spaces

$readfile = gc "\\server01\folder01\" + ($file) #It doesn't work
```

Thanks

Answer (score 100, accepted):

There are a couple of ways.  The most simple:

```
$readfile = gc \\server01\folder01\$file
```

Your approach was close:

```
$readfile = gc ("\\server01\folder01\" + $file)
```

You can also use [Join-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path?view=powershell-7) e.g.:

```
$path = Join-Path \\server01\folder01 $file
$readfile = gc $path
```

Comment: What if I want to add a sufix to an existent filename?
This does not work:
copy-Item "*.png" -destination "*.png"+(Get-Date -Format g).Replace("/", "-").Substring(0, 10)

Comment: Using `Join-Path` is way nicer. So you see what's going on and I've no clue what "gc" does. That's why I use -> `Join-Path -Path "path" -ChildPath "childpath"`

Comment: "gc" is an alias for Get-Content