# How to concat path and file name for creation and removal

Tags: string, powershell, concatenation, filepath

I'm trying the following.

```
$woohoo = "c:\temp\shabang"
New-Item -ItemType File $woohoo
```

This creates a file at desired location. However, I'd like to split the `$woo` and `$hoo` and go something like this.

```
$woo = "c:\temp"
$hoo = "shabang"
New-Item -ItemType File ($woo + $hoo)
```

This doesn't work and I need a hint on how to make it fly. [This suggestion](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/4e370143-eb34-4acc-96a2-301b102e69ec/concatenate-strings-and-variables?forum=winserverpowershell) nor [this on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783759/concatenate-network-path-variable) worked out when applied to my situation. Apparently - given path format is unsupported.

Suggestions?

## Edit

This is what it looks like:
[image]

## Edit 2

$woo = "c:\temp"; $hoo= "shabang"; New-Item -ItemType File (Join-Path $woo $hoo)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Doing `$woo + $hoo` does not return the proper filepath:

```powershell
PS > $woo = "c:\temp"
PS > $hoo = "shabang"
PS > $woo + $hoo
c:\tempshabang
PS >
```

Instead, you should use the [`Join-Path`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849799.aspx) cmdlet to concatenate `$woo` and `$hoo`:

```powershell
New-Item -ItemType File (Join-Path $woo $hoo)
```

See a demonstration below:

```powershell
PS > $woo = "c:\temp"
PS > $hoo = "shabang"
PS > Join-Path $woo $hoo
c:\temp\shabang
PS >
```

Comment: Seems there's something else wrong. I ran the exact line (new-item...) and got "unsupported format on path". Kindly, please see the edit to see I'm not lying.   :)

Comment: You need to copy and paste the exact code you are running and the exact error message.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Copy to where? Here? Please see edit (in 15 seconds).

Comment: @Bill_Stewart HA! Found the problem! The dir needs to exists in its wholeness. **Then** it works! No illegals there - just that the directory wasn't created.

Answer (score 2):

```
$path=Get-Location 
$file="myfile.json"
$path=Join-Path $path $file

#you can cast to a class if the class definition is known
$results = (Get-Content -Path $path  | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json)

foreach($tempObj in $results)
{
   $obj_vals=$tempObj|Select-Object -Property *
   Write-Host $obj_vals  -ForegroundColor Green
}
```