# How to create a directory and file while concatenating path and file name?

Tags: powershell

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24456429/how-to-concat-path-and-file-name-for-creation-and-removal#24456429) I discovered that the following:

```
$woo = "c:\temp"
$hoo = "shabang"
New-Item -ItemType File (Join-Path $woo $hoo)
```

works great but **only under assumption** that the path (*$woo*) exists. When I think of it, it makes sense since I'm creating a **file** not a **directory**.

How can I create **both**? Extra credit if there's a nifty way to create each one (directory and a file, respectively) only when they exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is actually quite simple.  Just add the [`-Force`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849795.aspx) flag:

```
New-Item -ItemType File -Force (Join-Path $woo $hoo)
```

This will create the new file and as many new directories as needed.  Note however that you still need write permissions for the parent directory.